# Does Rails need to be installed as a system gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

In every setup describing a configuring an environment with rbenv and Bundler, the instructions are always to install bundle as a system gem, using `gem install bundler`. Often, they'll also recommend [rbenv-bundler rbenv plugin](https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler), but [the maintainers of rbenv discourage this](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Plugins).

What's not described is how to install Rails. Initializing a new Rails project creates a basic Gemfile for bundler. However, in order to initialize a Rails project, one needs to have Rails installed. It seems weird and even wrong to make a directory, write a basic Gemfile that includes Rails, run `bundle install`, and then initialize Rails to the current directory. In fact, I doubt that would even work well, if it worked at all.

So, does Rails need to be installed as a system gem with `gem install rails`? If so, how does one manage multiple versions of Rails, particularly with rbenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally makes sense to *NOT* install rails as system gem.

Without messing up rbenv or other ruby version manager you use, below are brief steps to create (initialize) a new Rails app from a directory with a Gemfile:

```
mkdir rails_app
cd rails_app
vi Gemfile # Edit it to include a rails version you need
bundle --path vendor # Wait for bundler to finish
bundle exec rails new ./
```

The last step would ask: `Overwrite /path/to/rails_app/Gemfile? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]`. Input `y` to get the default Rails Gemfile content.

Note: the above steps specify the local `vendor` directory (inside the rails app folder) to avoid installing gems to system global scope.

Comment: This makes sense. It's a little bit of duplicate work - making the directory, making a Gemfile, then blowing that Gemfile away. It's a few more commands. But it does let everything except Bundler live in the vendor (or whatever you want to call it) directory.

Comment: it's actually a really bad idea to install it as a system Gem, perhaps unless you use a customized docker instance. It's a good idea to separate system and user-land libraries. A rails application is basically user-land from an OS perspective. So rbenv for the deploy user is better.

Comment: That's why in the example I install the gems to the vendor folder inside the app. Personally I also use Foreman/Heroku Local to manage other services (Database, Redis, etc) to isolate them to the app.

Comment: I guess the weird thing for me is that the things I've read about setting up rbenv and Rails gloss over the installation of Rails. They explain how to set up rbenv, some plugins, and install versions of Ruby, then set them globally and locally. Then, it goes to creating a new Rails app. It's like these steps are an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @ThomasOwens One reason is you don't create new app all the time, and most people would just use the "install rails as system gem" and "rails new app" from that approach. Advanced users/teams might use an app template (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html).

Answer (score 2):

Answer is no, you don't install rails as system gem. Create a project folder, add `.ruby-version` file and add the ruby version you would like in this file i.e. `2.3.0`. rbenv uses the version specified in this file and it won't be system's ruby.

Now you can do `gem install bundler` from this directory and create `Gemfile` and add your rails version. Now run `bundle install` and roll it on the tracks of RAILS.....

Answer (score 0):

Force rails to vendor gems.

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ bundle config --local path vendor
$ rails new .
```